# How to get the page arguments from URL in drupal 7

Tags: php, codeigniter, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

I have created on menu hook  in drupal 7

```
$items['assistance/product-help/%'] = array(
       'page callback' => 'product_water_serach',
   'access arguments' => array('access content'),
       'page arguments' => array(2),
       'access callback' => TRUE,
);
```

My my url is

```
http://example.com/assistance/product-help/abcd+%20test
```

my function is

```
function product_water_serach($product_name)
   {
     echo $product_name; 
   }
```

output is :  abcd test

My requirement is output should be :     abcd+ test

Kindly suggest solution for above.

Comment: If you are generating the `abcd+%20test` portion of the URL from `product_water_search()`, you'd want to insert a regex into that function. But are you simply trying to add the `+` character at the end of the first word, regardless of the word?

Comment: there is some misunderstanding here   my node title is abcd+ test and i want my node title to print as it is in product_water_search function

Comment: what happens if you go to: `http://example.com/assistance/product-help/abcd%2B%20test`